# Произвольное меню с эффектом LavaLamp

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Есть список элементов(в моем случае 6), под ними есть "плавающий" блок шириной равной одному элементу. При наведении на конкретный элемент списка плавающий блок должен проплыть от исходной позиции и встать под ним, а если убрать наведение, должен остаться на месте.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.wrapper ul li').mouseover(function(){
      $(this).addClass('current');
    });
 });
```

```css
.wrapper{
  width:800px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.wrapper ul{
  width:800px;
  height:95px;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
.wrapper ul li{
  width:95px;
  height:95px;
  margin-right:5px;
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:#33a030;
}
.cur-item{
  width:95px;
  height:30px;
  display:inline-block;
  position:absolute;
  left:50px;
  background-color:#33a030;
}
.current{
  background-color:#000!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="cur-item"></div>
</div>
```

Я думаю, возможно как-то через добавление класса реализовать, или по-другому как-то.

Найденное ниже решение работает только после перезагрузки страницы.

Comment: Используй http://api.jquery.com/animate/. Примеры использования найдешь по ссылке.

Comment: Должно получиться примерно так : http://ruseller.com/lessons/les1629/demo/index.html, только здесь сделано через css, а мне это не подходит.

Answer (score 2):

Можно решить эту проблему устанавливая в JS свойство `left`. 
Вот [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7f30t4bv/1/) с полным примером, а вот немного измененная JS-функция:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var item = document.getElementsByClassName('cur-item')[0];
    $('.wrapper ul li').hover(
        function(evt){
            $(this).addClass('current');
            item.style.left = this.offsetLeft + 'px';

        },
        function(evt) {
            $(this).removeClass('current');
            item.style.left = 50 + 'px';
        });
 });
```

P.S. Добавлю просьбу из комментария и небольшое улучшение, [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7f30t4bv/4/). Аминирование свойства `transform` не вызывает `repaint` у стилей и, например, в Firefox формированием картинки будет заниматься GPU, что благотворно скажется на скорости работы страницы.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var item = document.getElementsByClassName('cur-item')[0];
    $('.wrapper ul li').on('mouseenter',
        function(evt){
            item.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (this.offsetLeft + 100) + 'px)';
        });
 });
```

Comment: Ваще супер, а можно сделать такб чтобы когда hover убрал, она б на месте этом же осталась, А не в начало возвращалась?

Comment: Зачет! Спасибо!

Comment: @Александр, `hover` - алиас на два события, `mousenter` и `mouseleave`, соответственно убрав всё, что происходит на `mouseleave` добьёмся нужного эффекта.

Comment: Еще вопрос есть. Было б ваще круто, если бы этот блок возвращался к блоку с определенным классом(имеется ввиду блок с классом active, active присваивается li, чья ссылка внутри совпадает с урлом страницы. )

Comment: @Александр, в первом варианте я задал точку возврата. Вместо константного значения можно написать `offsetLeft` нужного Вам элемента.

Comment: А если у меня элементов списка 11, из них видно 6(как и у нас), и есть возможность листать по элементам(как слайдер реализовано, то есть по нажатии на лево или право видимая область списка сдвигается на 1 элемент). Соответственно можно ли сделать возврат к элементу с опред классом? или типо надо выщитать позицию этого элемента в нынешний момент и к ней вернуть?

Comment: Ну то есть получается, что активный элемент может быть в 1 из 6и видимых позиций

Comment: @Александр, ситуация никак не поменяется, если элементов будет больше в линии, сколько бы из них не было бы видно. Взять позицию элемента можно за константное время. Если вести поиск не из `document`, а из обертки этого списка, то потери производительности практически не будет. Все зависит от того, как будет реализован слайдер.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29435/discussion-between--and-rolandius).

Comment: Т.е. мне надо сделать вот так: function(evt) {
            $(this).removeClass('current');
            item.style.left = 48 + 'px';
        }); А вместо 48 как-то подставить значение активного элемента?

Comment: Скрипт работает только после ПЕРЕЗАГРУЗКИ страницы.......Это беда

Comment: @Александр, с первого раза все работает, проверьте консоль на наличие других ошибок. Прежде, чем обвинять, надо поискать проблему у себя.